# Laravel 4 Redirect::action() "Route not defined"

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm currently having troubles with Laravel 4. I would like to use slugs for forum categories and forum topics (slugs are unique). In order to determinate if the user is in a category or in a topic, I have this route:

```php
Route::get('forum/{slug}', function($slug) {

    $category = ForumCategory::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    if (!is_null($category))
        return Redirect::action('ForumCategoryController@findBySlug', array('slug' => $slug));

    else {

        $topic = ForumTopic::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        if (!is_null($topic))
            return Redirect::action('ForumTopicController@findBySlug', array('slug' => $slug));

        else
            return 'fail';

    }

});
```

And I have the following error when I try to reach a category:

`Route [ForumCategoryController@findBySlug] not defined.`

Here is my ForumCategoryController:

```php
class ForumCategoryController extends BaseController {

    public function findBySlug($slug) {

        $category = ForumCategory::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        return View::make('forum.category', array(
            'title'         => 'Catégorie',
            'category'      => $category
        ));

    }

}
```

Where is the problem ? Is there a way to do it better ? Help please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel is telling that you have to define a route to use `Route::action()`, something like:

```
Route::get('forum/bySlug/{slug}', 'ForumTopicController@findBySlug');
```

Because it will actually build an url and consumme it:

```
http://your-box/forum/bySlug/{slug}
```

For that it must find a route pointing to your action.

Comment: it doesn't make sense, cause if you register route in this way, there's no need to use action method, you can just use url::to()