# Laravel 5 - Failure to redirect a controller action

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have searched for the solutions but no luck.

Error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 602:
Action UserController@index not defined.
```

route.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {

        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
            $id = auth()->user()->id;

            return redirect()->action('UserController@index');



        });

        Route::post('/', 'UserController@update');

        Route::post('/edit', 'UserController@edit');



    });
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use DB;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.profile');
    }
```

Even though my index method is obviously set.... but error still pops up. Please help to spot the error. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Redirect::action() "Route not defined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416083/laravel-4-redirectaction-route-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Route Case

You're trying to redirect to a *non-existing route*. You've to define it:

```
Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
```

But, read further the issues below.

## Detected Issues

- `route.php` should be `routes.php`
- Change `/{id}` to `{id}`
- Why do you store the id in `$id` and redirect to the index action without doing anything with the $id?
- Your route paths are not very clear (why do you do a post to / for an update?)

Comment: Thanks for your correction and input! for the 3rd point, isn't my code trying to define what the {id} is by setting $id into the function?

for 4th point, just thinking coz in my update function I validate the data being submitted by the user and update its record in the database. Is it an improper way of doing that?